Multiple tables query with repository pattern
I have an ASP.NET Web API project, and have implemented repository and unitOfWork patterns.
I currently have a big SQL query that I want to implement in code, it includes a lot of tables and joins.
My current solution is just fetching data from repositories one by one, returning an in-memory value or IEnumerable (not an IQueryable as it defeats the purpose of repositories) and just joining them later and projecting them to a DTO.
But this makes 20 round trips to the database for 20 tables I'm using, and it's very inefficient.
How can I improve performance (mainly focused on lowering number of round trips to database) by following repository pattern?

and have implemented repository and unitOfWork patterns - why?

@SvyatoslavDanyliv reusability, testability, separation of responsibilities.


reusability - you can create extension methods. 2) testability - create in-memory Sqlite database and test it simple and easy. 3) separation... - that's what is performance gap in using ORM like EF using generic repository pattern. DbSet is already Repository, DbContext is already UoW.


@SvyatoslavDanyliv understand and thank you for suggestions, but removing current implementation pattern is not an option in my case.

Well, I know LINQ and query translation very well. If you do not expose IQueryable from your repositories, effective joins are not possible.

A repository shouldn't be 'per table', it should be 'per aggregate root object'.  If a table cannot exist without another one (e.g. a school class has a teacher and some students), then the repository should be able return a class and it's students in one query.  You should not have to query multiple times to retrieve related data (e.g. 1 query to get class, then another to retreive it's teacher and another to retrieve the students) .

@Neil okay that is interesting, need to look into that. Thanks!

@GertArnold Well, you supposed wrong that its my choice and I have tied my own hands, I wanted a technical explanation how to achieve that, not moral and philosophical advice. Where do you see complaining and refusing help part?

"(not an IQueryable as it defeats the purpose of repositories" - IQueryable does not defeat the purpose of a Repository.  It depends entirely on what the purpose of your repository is. If it is to try and abstract the truth that you are entrusting EF with managing data access, then 100% you are doing it for the wrong reasons. Ditch the repository immediately and use the DbContext/DbSets. There is absolutely no excuse to handcuff & gag an application behind an Abstraction for the sake of Abstraction then ask for miracles to somehow make it work.

When you find yourself in a deep hole and holding a shovel, the solution isn't always finding someone else to jump in and dig faster, ignoring the advice pointing you towards a ladder.

Your repositories are implemented at the wrong layer.

I currently have a big SQL query that I want to implement in code, it includes a lot of tables and joins.

Then there should be a single repository method that returns the result of that query.  Although in EF it would normally be shaped with multiple related objects, instead of a big flat query result.
A repository shouldn't be 'per table', it should be 'per aggregate root object'. If a table cannot exist without another one (e.g. a school class has a teacher and some students), then the repository should be able return a class and it's students in one query. You should not have to query multiple times to retrieve related data (e.g. 1 query to get class, then another to retreive it's teacher and another to retrieve the students)

This. When you look at implementing a repository pattern with EF you absolutely do not want a Generic repository pattern. EF already provides a generic repository through DbSet. Repositories at an aggregate root level can help organize data access for common use, enforce common low-level domain rules, (Authorization, soft-delete, etc.) and help simplify unit testing.  I implement repositories for these reasons at an aggregate root level, and leverage IQueryable to empower consumers to use projection, sorting, pagination, etc. It enforces core standard rules and is easier to mock out.

I don't think you can say "I need to change the design of this without changing the patterns I'm using".
I think you might have a boundary issue if you're doing 20 queries that you can't do in 1 Batch.
Solution 1:  Write SQL
SELECT top 10 * FROM database1.dbo.Users;
SELECT top 10 * FROM database2.dbo.Users;
SELECT top 10 * FROM database3.dbo.Users;
SELECT top 10 * FROM database4.dbo.Users;

Execute this as one sproc or command and parse each result into your DTOs.
If you're in MS SQL Server land you can use Linked Servers to cross boundaries.  I don't think this is a great idea, but pushes this logic into the DB side and makes it 1 round trip as far as the application is concerns.
Solution 2:  Do them concurrently in a Manager or Helper
Your manager will control getting data from your Repositories.
public class CrossDomainHelper
{
    public DTO.User[] Load()
    {
        IRepo[] rr = new IRepo[]{new RepoA(), new RepoB(), new RepoC(), new RepoD()… new RepoX()};
        var tasksToRun = rr.Select( r => r.Get10UsersAsync() ); // Do not await here
        var repoCompletions = await Task.WhenAll(tasksToRun);
        foreach(var c in repoCompletions)
        {
            DTO.User[] users = c;
            // Do something with them
        }
    }
}

Solution 3:  You need a DataWarehouse or some sort of Aggregation
If you're doing a bunch of queries all over the place that should be part of a single process, then create a single place for that.
Another SQL Server database that collects this information.  Maybe events in that update it's state.  The structure of this should be suited to the business question you are answering.
You could use CDC to create the events.  Or if you already have a system with an aggregate simply read those events and re-build something more suited to what you really want to query.
